# How I can get localized name of NSTimeZone?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, timezone

I'm wondering how can I get localized city name of identifier to NSTimeZone object.
Main condition - do not use any third party dictionaries or APIs

Comment: see  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382932/how-to-use-nstimezone-timezonewithname-with-a-city-name-from-rails-activesuppo

Comment: `TimeZone.current.identifier`

Comment: NSString * TimeZoneName=[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]name];